# Export multiple separated collections in postman

Tags: collections, import, postman

I want to export multiple separated collections to another user in postman.
How can I do that? How can I select multiple collections at a time while exporting them in postman?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export all collections in postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747235/export-all-collections-in-postman)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You have 3 different way to copy your multiple Collections to an other Client.

- Export each collection as one single file (Contra: can be time-Consuming)
- Export Whole Postman Dump over File->Settings->Data (Contra: You must delete some collections, environment- and global variables afterwards)[image: Screenshot]
- Share Your Collections over the Postman cloud (Contra: depending on the amount: you have to pay for it).