# Export all collections in postman

Tags: postman

I have postman with multiple collections

I can export one by one, but I don't find any option to export all as is, also when moving to team mode

Is there option to export all my collections to another user ?

Comment: For everyone exporting their entire postman data, note that you will need to manually separate them into separate collections and then convert them to v2 of the postman schema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142871/how-to-convert-postman-backup-file-into-collection-files

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can export all APIs, Collections, Environments, Globals, and Header Presets to a single data dump zip file.

To open the `Data` tab in the app (v8):

`Settings > Data Tab > Export Data`

[image: Postman]

Selecting `Export Data` will take you to the area where you can download all data from your account.

You will receive an email when the data is available to download, depending on the size of the data set, refreshing the page will cycle through the download *status* and eventually show the `Download` button.

[image: Export Page]

Importing the data zip file back into a Workspace can be done by selecting the `Import` button and selecting the file.

You will see a preview of the files that you're about to import, before importing them into the Workspace.

[image: Import]

---

[**Edit**]

In the latest version, the options under `⚙️ > Settings > Data` will look slightly different but the flow remains the same. The Importing of the data dump file can also be done from this location.

[image: Latest Version]

Comment: It's per collection operation

Comment: If you used that from the settings it would grab all the data. So all the collections. Did you try it?

Comment: In the newer versions of Postman, you'll find it at Preferences -> Data -> Export

Comment: There is no export data button under the settings > data tab, maybe this is no longer available for newer versions?

Comment: You must be logged in to see the data tab

Comment: If you must be logged in, then there's no recourse for people who created all these without logging in?

Comment: @DannyDainton settings button exports postman information in v1 format, while per collection operation supports either v2 or v2.1 which is inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Be aware that this will export all your workspaces

Comment: Documentation here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting/exporting-data/

Comment: There isn't any feature in Postman that exports Workspaces, this will export all the Collections.

Answer (score 12):

In Postman, open the wrench icon, then settings, then data, then Download. See images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it's similar to @DannyDainton answer

Comment: Agreed, but it's easier for some people to digest when viewing the images, especially because the layout has changed.

Comment: No such option exists

Answer (score 8):

Open the postman installed drive in my case it is C drive
Then users > your username > AppData > Roaming > Postman > then pickup the latest json backup file.
It will be named as backup.json
Now you can import this file on postman.
And you are good to go.

Comment: The question asked how to export, not how to import.

Comment: @dcolazin the method that other answers here suggest for exporting postman data do no longer seem to be working, there is no export data button under the settings > data tab anymore. Using a JSON backup as described on this answer actually did the trick, it even imported all of the environment variables collections.

Comment: @ChristosLytras but what if such backup file doesn't exists?

Comment: @dcolazin I don't know about that, a solution was there but they removed it. The backup file will be there if Postman has some collections/requests in it, and if you go and look inside that directory, there are plenty of older backup files, not only one. I wonder why they did remove the export data feature under the settings, I believe they did it to promote their cloud workspaces paid system. This answer now reflects what people can do in order to take the data from one installation and import to another. Do you know any current and valid way to create a local formal backup?

Comment: @ChristosLytras I'm using v10.12.13 and the accepted answer works for me, but no backup file exist locally

Comment: @dcolazin there is no export data under the settings on the latest version, here you can get informed on a [postman community related post](https://community.postman.com/t/backup-all-postman-collection-at-once/44030), and you can even check the [official documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/) that they have removed the settings > data export and moved that feature to the cloud. Backup files are created, so there is something wrong with your installation most likely.

Comment: In my case I wanted to back up the Scratch Pad data, and these backup files were just what I needed. Perhaps they don't exist if not using the Scratch Pad.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone else is looking for the export button in the `Data` tab but does not find it, this is because Postman devs [decided to remove this feature](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11738#issuecomment-1444267295) since v10.10.3, at least for those working locally in scratchpad. The feature is still there if you are using their cloud-based workspace.