# How to convert Postman backup file into Collection files

Tags: postman

I was using Postman without an account, with all my collections saved locally.
Today, my Postman was updated to stop allowing this, leaving only a "lightweight" client that cannot use collections.

I can only export a JSON dump "backup" file, but not an actual Collection V2 file, which I need to import to the tool that I will use in replacement of Postman.

How can I (with a tool or manually) convert the JSON dump into Collection files?

Do note: creating a Postman account is NOT an option. I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to create an account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem:

it seems the backup dump file contains the collections in postman version 1, in field `"collections"`:
if you only need the collections (i.e. not global environments etc) you can store each entry in `"collections"` to a separate file which would result in `v1` formatted collections.

If you need `v2` collections, you could convert them, e.g. with the `npm` package [postman-collection-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-collection-transformer) (for [Node.js](https://nodejs.org))

As an example, here is a simple conversion script based on `postman-collection-transformer`'s README

> replace `<postman_backup_dump.json>` and `<output-directory>` with appropriate strings; if the collections have names that cannot be used as file-names, you would need to do some additional changes when creating the output file name

```js
var transformer = require('postman-collection-transformer'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');


var collection = require('<postman_backup_dump.json>');
var options = {
    inputVersion: '1.0.0',
    outputVersion: '2.0.0',
    retainIds: true  // the transformer strips request-ids etc by default.
};

var outDir = '<output-directory>';


collection.collections.forEach(function(coll){

    transformer.convert(coll, options, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
        }

        var content = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
        var index = 0;
        var name = result.info.name + '.json';
        while(fs.existsSync(path.resolve(outDir, name))){
            name = result.info.name + '_' + (++index) + '.json';
        }
        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(outDir, name), content, 'utf-8');
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: A late thanks! I could convert to V2 collections, and Insomnia loaded them all right 